# Autocomplete rospy

Tags: rospy, ros-hydro, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning how to programming in ROS hydro for my master thesis. I want to use auto complete of rospy libraries in an editor. I can enter commands like catkin_make, roslaunch from terminal, it is not problem.  I tried Sublime Text 2 with  [SublimeJEDI](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI). I added `"python_package_paths": ["/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"],`  line to sublime_jedi.sublime-settings. It didn't autocomplete but when I removed this line and added another folder that contains my own code it autocompletes statement like charm. After that, I tried [PyDev](http://pydev.org/).  I added that path as a library folder. PyDev autocompletes but when I traverse in list, Eclipse freezes and stops working. Is there any way to use autocomplete when using rospy ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191367/autocomplete-rospy/) by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I setup Eclipse the way described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) and it works great. Have you tried that?

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [serdar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20095/serdar/) on 2014-08-27**:
I tried tutorial for Eclipse. Now I can import project but when I want to edit an python file eclipse freezes.